# How to get the data from views to template Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

From my model I am uploading a file , In my views I perform some operations on the file .I am using DetailView of CBV of Django , In which I get one object and perform some operations on it . Now I want the data (after performing the operations) in my template . I know how to show the file in my template because the file is in models . But the functions are not in models and I want to print those in my template.
**My models.py is :**

```html
class FileUpload(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True , null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files')




    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')
```

**my views.py is :**

```html
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = "object_list"
    template_name = "post_detail.html"


    def get_object(self, *args,**kwargs):
        request = self.request
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        instance = FileUpload.objects.get(id = pk) #I want to print this  instance

        if instance is None:
            raise Http404("File Does not EXIST")
        else:
            pdfFileObj = open(instance.file.path, 'rb')
            pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
            print('number of pages = ',pdfReader.numPages)
            pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
            print(pageObj.extractText())     #I want to print this
            query = pageObj.extractText()

            for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=2):
                print(j)       #I want to print this

            pdfFileObj.close()
        return instance
```

Comment: You can move all that stuff to `get_context_data` so you can pass those things you want to print to the template

Comment: Sir how ? . I do not know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to first add the queryset as `FileUpload.objects.all()`, in order for your detail view to know where to find your object automatically. That way, you don't have to write your own `get_object`.

You can then move all those processing to `get_context_data`, and then pass those to the template if you want to display them, like this:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = "object_list"
    template_name = "post_detail.html"
    queryset = FileUpload.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        pdfFileObj = open(self.object.file.path, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
        print('number of pages = ',pdfReader.numPages)
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
        extracted_text = pageObj.extractText())
        query = pageObj.extractText()

        search_results = []
        for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=2):
            search_results.append(j)

        pdfFileObj.close()

        context['extracted_text'] = extracted_text
        context['search_results'] = search_results

        return context
```

You should then be able to use them in your template:

```
{{ extracted_text }}

{{ search_results }}
```

And to print the instance, just use:

```
{{ object }}
```

Comment: can you explain that what is the difference between get_object and get _context_data

Comment: `get_object` is as the name suggests, just getting the object that the detail view will work on. `get_context_data` is responsible for gathering all context/objects that can be used in your template. So if you want to use something in your template, you need to use `get_context_data` and add it to the `context`